# Unit testing side effects in Elixir

Tags: unit-testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm writing a unit test for a function that calls out to module as part of a side effect of invoking it:

```
defmodule HeimdallrWeb.VerifyController do
  use HeimdallrWeb, :controller

  def verify(conn, _params) do
    [forwarded_host | _tail] = get_req_header(conn, "x-forwarded-host")

    case is_preview_page?(forwarded_host) do
      {:ok, false} ->
        conn |> send_resp(200, "")

      {:ok, %Heimdallr.Commits.Commit{} = commit} ->
        Heimdallr.Commits.touch_commit(commit)
        conn |> send_resp(200, "")

      {:not_found, _reason} ->
        conn |> send_resp(200, "")
    end
  end
end
```

The side effect is triggered from the line `Heimdallr.Commits.touch_commit(commit)`.

A few questions about this:

1. Should my unit test be concerned with testing the effects of the `touch_commit` method.
2. If so, should I think about passing in a generic "touch" function to verify method to make it easier to test. This might be difficult due to the nature of Phoenix / Elixirs routing system, I haven't investigated.

If I was using Rails / Ruby / Rspec then I'd set an expectation that a class level method would be called on the `HeimdallrCommits` module.

My concern and reason for writing the test is that in the future I may accidentally remove the functionality that is touching a commit by deleting or commenting out the line etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 1: No. And that is to keep the complexity low in your test. You only want to test (whatever it is you want to test) in a method, the rest should be mocked ignored. What you could do is verify what your method have invoked touch_commit - should be part of a good mocking framework. Those are my 5 cent, sorry to say that I am not familiar with phoenix/elixir so I can't give you any working examples. Like the verify method i Mockito or Moq is what I am thinking of..